# MS Access duplicate values using SUM

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm having trouble writing a query in Microsoft Access 2016 that will show the sum of an Expense for a particular event, the sum of the signs that event produced, along with the year, event description and company name.

I think I am missing something simple, and am going to feel ridiculous once someone points it out. Hopefully I managed to format my question well enough that it is easy to spot!

Here are the tables involved, along with the dummy data I am testing with.

```
All_Company           Company_Event             

------------------    ---------------------------
|  ID  | Company |    | ID |  EventDescription  |
|------|---------|    |----|--------------------|
|  1   | Crapple |    | 1  |      Concert       |
|  2   | Rito    |    | 2  |       Party        |
------------------    ---------------------------

Company_Target_Actual
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  All_CompanyID | Company_EventID   | Year | Quarter | Signed |
|----------------|-------------------|------|---------|--------|
|        1       |         2         | 2015 |    1    |    1   |
|        1       |         2         | 2015 |    2    |    0   |
|        1       |         2         | 2015 |    3    |    3   |
|        1       |         2         | 2015 |    4    |    1   |
----------------------------------------------------------------

Budget_Company_Expense
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | All_CompanyID | Company_EventID | Year | Category | SubCategory| Expense |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |       1       |        2        | 2015 |   ABCD   |    123     |   40    |
| 2  |       1       |        2        | 2015 |   ABCD   |    cat     |   113   |
| 3  |       1       |        2        | 2015 |   ABCD   |    dog     |   71    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my code for the query, I broke it up from the ugly Access long lines of code to make it easier to read.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW All_Company.Company, Budget_Company_Expense.Year, 
Budget_Company_Expense.Company_EventID, Company_Event.EventDescription, 
Sum(Budget_Company_Expense.Expense) AS [Sum Of Expense USD],
Sum(Company_Target_Actual.Signed) AS [Sum Of Signed]
FROM Company_Event 
    INNER JOIN ((All_Company 
    INNER JOIN Company_Target_Actual 
    ON All_Company.[ID] = Company_Target_Actual.[All_CompanyID]) 
INNER JOIN Budget_Company_Expense 
    ON All_Company.[ID] = Budget_Company_Expense.[All_CompanyID]) 
    ON Company_Event.[ID] = Budget_Company_Expense.[Company_EventID]
GROUP BY All_Company.Company, Budget_Company_Expense.Year,
Budget_Company_Expense.Company_EventID, Company_Event.EventDescription;
```

and here is the result from running my query

```
Result
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Company | Year | Company_EventID | EventDescription | Sum of Expense USD | Sum of Signed|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Crapple | 2015 |        2        |      Party       |       $896.00      |       15     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, it is summing as if the total signs (5) happened 3 times (the number of entries in the Company_Target_Actual table) and vis versa for the Expense. Any help on my issue would be greatly appreciated, 
and if I forgot any information that may help find my mistake please let me know what else I can provide!

Comment: start selecting from All_Company first then change your joins to left joins. You are missing dollar amounts for the actuals table too. You should get a sum from budget vs actual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider splitting the query into two aggregations, one to sum `Signed` in Company_Target_Actual and the other to sum `Expense` in Business_Company_Expense. Then, join the two queries by Company, Event, and Year which are the grouping factors.

Below uses two derived tables (subqueries in `FROM/JOIN` clause). However, you can very well save either one as a separate query and then join them in final query:

```
SELECT t1.Company, t1.Year, t1.Company_EventID, t1.EventDescription,
       t2.[Sum Of Expense USD], t1.[Sum of Signed]
FROM

   (SELECT ac.ID AS CompanyID, ac.Company, ca.Year, ca.Company_EventID, ev.EventDescription, 
           SUM(ca.Signed) AS [Sum Of Signed]
    FROM (Company_Target_Actual ca
    INNER JOIN Company_Event ev 
          ON ca.Company_EventID = ev.ID)
    INNER JOIN All_Company ac
          ON ca.All_CompanyID = ac.ID
    GROUP BY ac.ID, ac.Company, ca.Year, ca.Company_EventID, ev.EventDescription) AS t1

INNER JOIN

   (SELECT ac.ID AS CompanyID, ac.Company, be.Year, be.Company_EventID, ev.EventDescription, 
           SUM(be.Expense) AS [Sum Of Expense USD]
    FROM (Budget_Company_Expense be
    INNER JOIN Company_Event ev 
          ON be.Company_EventID = ev.ID)
    INNER JOIN All_Company ac
          ON be.All_CompanyID = ac.ID
    GROUP BY ac.ID, ac.Company, be.Year, be.Company_EventID, ev.EventDescription) AS t2

ON t1.CompanyID = t2.CompanyID 
AND t1.Company_EventID = t2.Company_EventID
AND t1.Year = t2.Year
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and makes so much more sense than the way I was approaching it. Thank you so much.